# jQueryMobile filter on more than one select

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've created a form with a filterable select with jquery mobile as explained [in this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/) and it works. I cannot add the filter to many select. How can i add the filter to the others select i have in my form? I've tried in many ways, but I did not succeed.

Code for the form:

```
<label for="filter-menu" class="select">Cerca per itinerario</label>
<select id="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="c">
    <option value="SFO">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="LAX">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="YVR">Vancouver</option>
    <option value="YYZ">Toronto</option>
</select>


<label for="filter-menu2" class="select">Cerca per itinerario</label>
    <select id="filter-menu2" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="c">
        <option value="USA">San Francisco</option>
        <option value="USA">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="CAN">Vancouver</option>
        <option value="CAN">Toronto</option>
    </select>
```

Here's the javascript, copied from the jQuery mobile site:

```
$.mobile.document

    // "filter-menu-menu" is the ID generated for the listview when it is created
    // by the custom selectmenu plugin. Upon creation of the listview widget we
    // want to prepend an input field to the list to be used for a filter.
    .on( "listviewcreate", "#filter-menu-menu", function( e ) {
        var input,
            listbox = $( "#filter-menu-listbox" ),
            form = listbox.jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            listview = $( e.target );

        // We store the generated form in a variable attached to the popup so we
        // avoid creating a second form/input field when the listview is
        // destroyed/rebuilt during a refresh.
        if ( !form ) {
            input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
            form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );

            input.textinput();

            $( "#filter-menu-listbox" )
                .prepend( form )
                .jqmData( "filter-form", form );
        }

        // Instantiate a filterable widget on the newly created listview and
        // indicate that the generated input is to be used for the filtering.
        listview.filterable({ input: input });
    })

    // The custom select list may show up as either a popup or a dialog,
    // depending how much vertical room there is on the screen. If it shows up
    // as a dialog, then the form containing the filter input field must be
    // transferred to the dialog so that the user can continue to use it for
    // filtering list items.
    //
    // After the dialog is closed, the form containing the filter input is
    // transferred back into the popup.
    .on( "pagebeforeshow pagehide", "#filter-menu-dialog", function( e ) {
        var form = $( "#filter-menu-listbox" ).jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            placeInDialog = ( e.type === "pagebeforeshow" ),
            destination = placeInDialog ? $( e.target ).find( ".ui-content" ) : $( "#filter-menu-listbox" );

        form
            .find( "input" )

            // Turn off the "inset" option when the filter input is inside a dialog
            // and turn it back on when it is placed back inside the popup, because
            // it looks better that way.
            .textinput( "option", "inset", !placeInDialog )
            .end()
            .prependTo( destination );
    });
```

I cannot understand in which way he attach the filter to #filter-menu and the way to do the same thing with #filter-menu2 and to other selects.

Comment: You need to show us, in the question, what you've got and tried.

Comment: at this time, because nothing worked, i turn back to original code linked in this page [link]http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Comment: @HugoYates - I paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM creates IDs automatically for the filter listbox. So for filter-menu, the id of the listbox is filter-menu-listbox. In your case you also need to deal with filter-menu2-listbox:

```
$.mobile.document
    .on( "listviewcreate", "#filter-menu-menu", function( e ) {
        var input,
            listbox = $( "#filter-menu-listbox" ),
            form = listbox.jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            listview = $( e.target );

        if ( !form ) {
            input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
            form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );

            input.textinput();

            $( "#filter-menu-listbox" )
                .prepend( form )
                .jqmData( "filter-form", form );
        }

        listview.filterable({ input: input });
    })
    .on( "pagebeforeshow pagehide", "#filter-menu-dialog", function( e ) {
        var form = $( "#filter-menu-listbox" ).jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            placeInDialog = ( e.type === "pagebeforeshow" ),
            destination = placeInDialog ? $( e.target ).find( ".ui-content" ) : $( "#filter-menu-listbox" );

        form
            .find( "input" )

            .textinput( "option", "inset", !placeInDialog )
            .end()
            .prependTo( destination );
    })
    .on( "listviewcreate", "#filter-menu2-menu", function( e ) {
        var input,
            listbox = $( "#filter-menu2-listbox" ),
            form = listbox.jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            listview = $( e.target );

        if ( !form ) {
            input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
            form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );

            input.textinput();

            $( "#filter-menu2-listbox" )
                .prepend( form )
                .jqmData( "filter-form", form );
        }

        listview.filterable({ input: input });
    })
    .on( "pagebeforeshow pagehide", "#filter-menu2-dialog", function( e ) {
        var form = $( "#filter-menu2-listbox" ).jqmData( "filter-form" ),
            placeInDialog = ( e.type === "pagebeforeshow" ),
            destination = placeInDialog ? $( e.target ).find( ".ui-content" ) : $( "#filter-menu2-listbox" );

        form
            .find( "input" )

            .textinput( "option", "inset", !placeInDialog )
            .end()
            .prependTo( destination );
    });
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vshcbyed/)**

Comment: Hi @ezanker, thank you. Another question: there's a way to do it in a recursive way? I have many select to apply the filter and rewrite the code for any select seems to me not a good idea. Maybe i can try with jQuery "each" function.

Comment: @CosimoAmica, You can certainly use the each function. I have updated the fiddle to do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vshcbyed/1/